# Get object key and use it as a property in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I currently have this JSON

**input**

```
[
    {
        "A": {
            "name": "Dog"
        }
    },
    {
        "B": {
            "name": "Cat"
        }
    }
]
```

I have the following classes:

```
public class Pet {

  @JsonProperty("name")
  String name = "";

  @JsonIgnore
  String id  = "";
}
```

I want to have this output

> note: (this is just a representation of the deserialized objects)

```
 Pet [ name = "Dog" , id = "A"],
 Pet [ name = "Cat" , id = "B"]
```

Comment: What you want is not a valid JSON statement. What you can achieve is `[{ name = "Dog" , id = "A"},{..}]` but without the "Pet" statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `List<Pet>`, not `PetList` class. In this case Jackson will do what you want - `[ { pet1..}, {pet2...} ]` And `Pet` will have `name` and `id`.

**EDIT:** if you want

```
[
    {
        "A": {
            "name": "Dog"
        }
    },
    {
        "B": {
            "name": "Cat"
        }
    }
]
```

then you need to put a `Map<String, IdClass>` into your `Pet`, put in this map `"A": new IdObject()`, and IdObject should have `String name = "Dog"`

Comment: yeah I forgot it should be a ``List<Pet>`` , I have updated my post. Will the ``id`` property be taken from the object's key?

Comment: if you provide @JsonIgnore on 'id' then no, it shouldn't be serialized

Comment: even though I remove ``@JsonIgnore`` the id is not inside the object as a property, it is being used as a key. Check this out http://i.imgur.com/8nuwtmn.png